# Is this the correct "internal field name"?

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2010

I think I'm interpreting this internal field name correctly, but my references that use it to match don't work.

...Field=How%5Fx0020%5Fmany%5Fx0020%5FQuestions%5Fx

So I figure this fieldname is How_x0020_many_x0020_Questions_x

I'm using it here:

```
$.each(BothArrays.AryObjctvs, function(indx,contents) { // how to use: console.log(indx + "-" + contents.Title);
  var QSubsetAry = $.grep(BothArrays.Exam_Q, function(n){
    return  (n.Objectives.toLowerCase().indexOf(contents.Title.toLowerCase()) >= 0);            
  })
  //THis shows me the correct number of recs when the array is filtered.
  console.log("QSubsetAry.length=" + QSubsetAry.length); 
  //this is always zero
  console.log("Occurences should = " + contents.How_x0020_many_x0020_Questions_x)  
});
```

Comment: What happens when you do this `console.log(JSON.stringify(contents))`?  Do you see the fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint converts spaces to `_x0020_` for internal field names, and underscores are encoded as %5F. So yes, you are correct.